# How to display a single product rating in Google rich snippets using Schema.org

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

**Most examples shows multiple ratings**

I want to show ratings in Google but all the rating examples I have found shows multiple people votes.

**I want to show ONE author rating**

What I want is to show just one rating made by the team behind the site, like the screenshot on this URL: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-hreview/

**So far...**

This is not what I want but maybe a start.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Test</span>
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating"
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
   Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.5</span>/5
   based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">11</span> customer reviews
  </div>
</div>
```

**Accepted answer**

- Show me some rich snippet code OR a good link to a good example of
  this.
- It should work with
  http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope="">
    <meta content="admin" itemprop="author" />
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope="" itemprop="reviewRating">
        <meta content="1" itemprop="worstRating" />
        <meta content="3.5" itemprop="ratingValue" />
        <meta content="5" itemprop="bestRating" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The format keeps changing over and over. On top of that search engines have started validating reviews. I would use microformats.org hproduct instead as currently (2013) schema.org does not allow non aggregate reviews of products

```
<div id="review">
<div class="hproduct">
<div><a class="url" href="product.html"><span class="fn">Test</span></a></div>
<div class="description pro contra">A short description</div>
<div class="review hreview">
<abbr class="dtreviewed" title="2015-01-01"></abbr>
<abbr class="best" title="5"></abbr>
<abbr class="rating" title="3.5"></abbr>
<abbr class="worst" title="1"></abbr>
<div style="display:inline-block">
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Horrible!" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Very Bad!" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Not Good" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="OK" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Not Bad" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Good" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Pretty Good" class="star" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Very Good" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Excellent!" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" name="total" title="Perfect!" class="star" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block" class="reviewer vcard">
<span class="fn" itemprop="name">Anonymous</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```